# How do I prevent the buttons from appearing again when clicking the button in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a program that solves linear programming exercises using the tkinter, matplotlib, and pulp libraries. However, I'm new to Python. Can someone tell me what error I'm making? I want that when I press 'Accept', it removes the old input fields and creates new ones, but I also want this to happen with the buttons because when I press them, some buttons remain at the top.

```
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib import *
from pulp import *

# Creates the application class that initializes the program
class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None): # Program initializer: calls all created methods and executes them
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.text_boxes = [] # List to store text entry fields
        
    # This method creates all the widgets for the program
    def create_widgets(self):
        Label(self, text="Enter Number of Variables").pack()
        
        self.num_variables_entry = Entry(self, justify='center')
        self.num_variables_entry.pack()
        
        Button(self, text="Accept", command=self.create_text_boxes).pack()
        
    def create_text_boxes(self):
        # Deletes previous text entry fields
        for box in self.text_boxes:
            box.destroy()
            
        self.text_boxes.clear()  # Clears the list of previous text entry fields
        
        Label(self, text="Objective Function").pack()
        num_boxes = int(self.num_variables_entry.get())  # Retrieves the number entered in the Entry
        for i in range(num_boxes):
            entry = Entry(self)
            entry.pack()
            self.text_boxes.append(entry)  # Adds the new text entry fields to the list
            
        Button(self, text="Add Constraint").pack()
        Button(self, text="Solve").pack()
            
root = Tk()
myapp = App(master=root)
myapp.master.title("Linear Programming")
myapp.mainloop()
```

I tried doing the same thing I did with the text boxes, but it didn't work. It still leaves the buttons at the top.

```
def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        self.text_boxes = []
        self.buttons = []
        self.create_widgets()

def create_text_boxes(self):
        for box in self.text_boxes:
            box.destroy()
            
        self.text_boxes.clear()
        
        Label(self, text="Objective Function").pack()
        num_boxes = int(self.num_variables_entry.get())
        for i in range(num_boxes):
            entry = Entry(self)
            entry.pack()
            self.text_boxes.append(entry)
        
        for btn in self.buttons:
            btn.destroy()
        self.buttons.clear()
        
        self.create_buttons()
    
    def create_buttons(self):
        Button(self, text="Add Constraint").pack()
        Button(self, text="Solve").pack()
```

Comment: you have to assign buttons to variable - `b = Button(...)` - and later you can use `b.pack()` to show it and `b.forget()` to remove it. Or use `b.destroy()` to remove it from screen and from memory.

Comment: Frankly, I don't understand you. You have list `self.buttons` but you never add buttons to this list - so later `for btn in self.buttons: btn.destroy()`  can't remove them. But you have list `self.text_boxes` for all inputs and you append all `Entry` to this list. Why don't you do the same with `Buttons`? And this is your problem.

Comment: BTW: it may be simpler to create `Frame` and add all widgets to this frame (and frame add to window), and later you have to remove only this frame to remove all widgets.